# RegEx: Delete everything after the first word to the next line

Tags: regex

What regular expression is used to delete everything except the first word from each line:

Data:

```
JAMES          3.318  3.318      1
JOHN           3.271  6.589      2
ROBERT         3.143  9.732      3
```

I'm trying to do this in Notepad++ as a replace.

Comment: Regular expressions are used to find complex matches across strings, not to manipulate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what regex implementation you're using.

the regex `^[A-Za-z_]+` will capture the first word on a line. So, you can capture this first word and print it out and you're good to go, if your implementation permits.

If you need to use substitute, you can substitute `^([A-Za-z_]+).*` for `\1`
E.g., in vi, you would use the command `:%s/^\([A-Za-z_]+\).*/\1/`

Comment: Actually I was trying to do it in Notepad++, and none of these seem to to do.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that bit for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `^(\s*\w+)\s+.*$` with `\1` and it will retain the first word and delete the rest of the line.

Answer (score 2):

In perl notation:

```
s/^(\w+).*$/$1/
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, this post is a few years old ... ;)
Anyway:

Assuming that a word is any sequence of characters followed by space:

The regex would be:
`/\s.*/g`

## "." stands for anything but line break.

in vi you would use following command to "delete" the rest of any line after the first word:
`:%s/\s.*//g`